# how to apply select2 library in textbox from tagging

Tags: javascript, php

Using select 2 library which html code i add into my page for tag add in text box
        https://select2.github.io/examples.html
        please anyone help to using this

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tags"><?php echo  __('Tags') ?></label>
                <textarea rows="2" class="form-control js-example-tags"  id="list_tags" name="list_tags"><?php echo($tags); ?></textarea>
                <p class="help-block"><?php echo  __('Use commas between tags') ?></p>
              </div>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $('.js-example-tags').select2({
              tags: ["red", "green", "blue"]
            })
</script>
    i want to create like https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags this way but don't know how to do this
```

i can try to put html code but don;t get any perfect output

Comment: Tell us what you've tried, code any error you're facing etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you replace textarea to select? I think select2 apply for select tag

Comment: This should be comment not answer.

Comment: this answer should be not helpful to me